# Partial correlation coefficient with complex survey data

Tags: r, correlation, survey

I am working with complex survey data and trying to find a way to estimate a partial correlation coefficient based on a complex survey design. Is anyone familiar with an R package or function to estimate partial correlation coefficients with complex survey data?

Comment: hi, most of what's available in R is probably here  http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/

Comment: Thanks. I know that website. I looked there, but wasn't able to find a direct response to my question.

Answer (score 1):

`svyvar()` will estimate the population covariance matrix. The inverse of this (use `solve()`) is the population precision matrix, and if you scale the diagonal to 1 (use `cov2cor()`) you get the population partial correlation matrix.