# Partial spearman correlation with complex survey data

Tags: survey, spearman-rho, partial-correlation

I'm looking for info on how to compute both the partial spearman correlations and p-values for complex survey data.

There was a similar question for pearson correlations here: [Partial correlation coefficient with complex survey data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449503/partial-correlation-coefficient-with-complex-survey-data).

Thomas Lumley had the following answer to that question:

> svyvar() will estimate the population covariance matrix. The inverse of this (use solve()) is the population precision matrix, and if you scale the diagonal to 1 (use cov2cor()) you get the population partial correlation matrix.

What I would like to know is (1) does this work for spearman correlations, (2) does this reproduce p-values and (3) if the answer to either of the previous questions is "no", is there another way to find the partial spearman correlations and corresponding p-values in complex survey data